# Delete Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location from Header

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rest-api

I want to delete ocp-apim-trace location once api call made in APIM policy.
Please suggests.`enter code here`

Comment: Usually this is not a problem, because the it's onyl available for administrators:
_[AZURE.NOTE] API Inspector traces are only generated and made available for requests containing subscription keys that belong to the administrator account._

https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector.md

Comment: Headers in general can be removed by using the policy:
        <set-header name="my-header" exists-action="delete">
        </set-header>

Answer (score 0):

This header is added to response only if call is made with subscription key belonging to admin AND if request had OCP-APIM-Trace: True header. So it will be absent for normal requests.